# Override NSLOG in prefix.pch IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I read this article: http://weakreference.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/overriding-nslog-on-ios/.

The idea of the article is to add these two things to the prefix.pch file of your app, so that you can override the behavior of NSLog.

The two things I'm adding are:

```
#define NSLog(...) customLogger(__VA_ARGS__);
```

and

```
void customLogger(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, format);
    NSMutableString * message = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:format
        arguments:argumentList];

    [message appendString:@"Our Logger!"]; // Our custom Message!
    NSLogv(message, argumentList); // Originally NSLog is a wrapper around NSLogv.
    va_end(argumentList);
    [message release];
}
```

xCode throws an error match-o error, that it finds duplicates of customLogger.

Has anyone successfully overridden NSLog?

Thanks!

**Edit in response to Rob:**

Okay, great. We're making progress! I moved thing just like you asked. Here's what we have now:

My custom logger:

```
void customLogger(NSString *format, ...) {

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    va_end(args);
    [newLogger log:format withArgs:args];
}

//This is a newLogger Method
+ (void) log:(NSString *)format withArgs:(va_list) args{

    NSArray *occ = [format componentsSeparatedByString:@"%@"];

    NSInteger characterCount = [occ count]; 

    NSArray *stringItems = [format componentsSeparatedByString:@"%@"];

    NSMutableString *tmp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@",[stringItems objectAtIndex:0]];

    for( int i = 1; i < characterCount; i++ ) {
        NSString *value = va_arg(args, NSString *);
        [tmp appendString:value];
        [tmp appendString:[stringItems objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    // Need to alter the above and actually do something with the args! 
    [tmp appendString:@"\n"];
    [[newLogger sharedInstance].logBuffer appendString:tmp];

    if ([newLogger sharedInstance].textTarget){
        [[newLogger sharedInstance].textTarget setText:sharedInstance.logBuffer];
    }
}
```

When I call +log, I get a SIBABRT error on Thread 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you defined `customLogger` in your `.pch` file.  That means every `.m` file includes it, so every `.o` file your project creates contains its own copy of `customLogger`.  That's why you get duplicate symbol definition errors from the linker.

You need to just declare `customLogger` in the `.pch`, like this:

```
void customLogger(NSString *format, ...);
```

And create a `customLogger.m` file containing the definition.

Comment: Okay, that works...partially.

Now, I'm going to overriding NSLOG. This means, I'm putting a line like: #define NSLog(...) customLogger(__VA_ARGS__);, then in the custom logger function executing:

void customLogger(NSString *format, ...) {
    
    va_list args;
 va_start(args, format);
    
 va_end(args);
    
    [newLogger log:format withArgs:args];
    
}

..This gets everything passed to NSLog, and sends them to my newLogger. 

--Doing these things gives me a mysterious crash, that is simply SIGABRT on thread 1.

Comment: You need to call `va_end` after you call `newLogger`, not before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. It overrides NSLog. Write below code in ClassName-Prefix.pch file at the end

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#   define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

and in ViewController.m file,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DLog(@"printing from DLog");

    DLog(@"printing again from DLog");

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

This will print the sentence in console. 
Let me know if you find difficulties.

Comment: This won't override anything, this creates a new logging system that uses NSLog in the end anyway :(